# (double) for-loop with variable indexing in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have a buffer with IDs which looks like this
    `InBuffer={ID1,ID2,ID3,...}`

I need to iterate through, every time using the ID in a function that returns pointers to the Data assigned to this ID and the size of the Data. I then need to fill in another buffer with the result which is of the form

```
OutBuffer={ID1,SIZE1,DATA1.WORD1,...,DATA1.WORDSIZE1,
    ID2,SIZE2,DATA2.WORD1,...,DATA2.WORDSIZE2,
    ...,
    IDN,SIZEN,DATAN.WORD1,...,DATAN.WORDSIZEN
}
```

I am having problems with forming the whole for-loop for this and the indexing of it, mainly because each SIZE variable can be different. It should be simple but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
// For example
// Iterate through the remaining of the Request Buffer (m=0,1 already set) 
for (m = 2; m < InBuffer; m++)`
{ 
  OutBuffer[m] = InBuffer[m];
  returnPointersToDataAndSizeFunction(InBuffer[m], &SIZE, &DATA);
  OutBuffer[m + 1] = SIZE; // e.g. SIZE = 2, therefore DATA has 2 fields 
  OutBuffer[m + 2] = DATA.1; // first field  
  OutBuffer[m + 3] = DATA.2; // second field
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: Please add some more code that we can help you. Especially of the bit you described in the second paragraph.

Comment: @user3374479, it isn't clear still.  Perhaps you could write a clear example with actual data and associated code.

Comment: @user3374479 when you don't know how your indices should flow into your algorithm, you should start your comment by declaring them and better use names from your math textbook, such as: `1<i<m`, `0<=j<n`, where m is the size of the InBuffer and n is the size of the outbuffer. (Just kind of, as you cannot tell anything about n but n>2*m, when you algorithm starts.

Comment: Code without variable declarations is meaningless to post. When reading someone else's code, the very first thing you check is the types of all variables involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're using `m` to index both buffers:

```
for (m = 2; m < InBuffer; m++)
{ 
    OutBuffer[m]=InBuffer[m];
```

but then you're using offsets from `m` for the additional data in `OutBuffer`:

```
OutBuffer[m+1]=SIZE;
OutBuffer[m+2]=DATA;
```

So, what you do think is going to happen in the next iteration of the loop? Say you go through the loop the first time, so that `m` is 2. The next time, it's `m++`, i.e. 3, and you make this assignment again:

```
OutBuffer[m]=InBuffer[m];
```

But you already assigned something at `m[3]`, and that's the `SIZE` value from the previous iteration. You also assigned `DATA` at `m[4]`, and that's going to be overwritten by the `SIZE` value in this iteration. Eventually, you'll end up with `OutBuffer` containing exactly what's in `InBuffer`, plus the `SIZE` and `DATA` values for the very last ID.

You need to use a different variable to index `OutBuffer`, something like:

```
for (m = 2, n = m; m < InBuffer; m++) {
    OutBuffer[n++] = InBuffer[m];
    returnPointersToDataAndSizeFunction(InBuffer[m],&SIZE,&DATA);
    OutBuffer[n++] = SIZE;
    OutBuffer[n++] = DATA;
}
```

There are some other problems as well. For example, the condition in the `for` loop shouldn't compare `m` to `InBuffer`, but should instead compare `m` and the number of entries in `InBuffer`. But just straightening out your indexing should be a big step forward.

**Update:** I just noticed that the data for each ID is larger than just one field. You'll need another loop inside the first one, then, so that you end up with something like this:

```
for (m = 2, n = m; m < InBuffer; m++) {
    OutBuffer[n++] = InBuffer[m];
    returnPointersToDataAndSizeFunction(InBuffer[m],&SIZE,&DATA);
    OutBuffer[n++] = SIZE;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        OutBuffer[n++] = DATA[i];
    }
}
```

If `DATA` is a structure with fields rather than an array, then you may need a series of `if` statements to check whether each field should be included or not. You can't use the value of a variable like `i` as the name of a field, i.e. you can't say `DATA.i` where `i` is a variable. I don't think a C structure can have field names that are numbers -- identifiers generally have to start with a letter or underscore, so trying to do that won't make much sense anyway. If you have control over the type of `DATA`, you should make it an array instead of a structure. So your loop would look more like this:

```
for (m = 2, n = m; m < InBuffer; m++) {
    OutBuffer[n++] = InBuffer[m];
    returnPointersToDataAndSizeFunction(InBuffer[m],&SIZE,&DATA);
    OutBuffer[n++] = SIZE;
    i = 0;
    if (i++ < SIZE) { OutBuffer[n++] = DATA.field1; }
    if (i++ < SIZE) { OutBuffer[n++] = DATA.field2; }
    // and so on for each field in DATA's type 
}
```

Comment: I like the for loop more than your last example. Generally it is often better to avoid increase and index operators (`OutBuffer[n++]`) in one statement. At least until you exactly know what you're doing.

Comment: Caleb you're still comparing int with pointer: `m < InBuffer` vs `InBuffer[m]` - not going to end well

Comment: Thank you @Caleb, while transferring my code for the example, I clumsily did not compare to the length of the InBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

As Caleb pointed out you should use one variable for each array.

If you're saying that  `DATA` can contain more than one element then you should increase the variable for `outBuffer` by `SIZE` each iteration. Also use a loop to asign `DATA`s fields to `OutBuffer`

```
int n = XXX; // set n to the first element you need to assign an ID to
for (m = 2; m < ElementsInBuffer; m++)
{
  OutBuffer[n] = InBuffer[m];
  returnPointersToDataAndSizeFunction(InBuffer[m],&SIZE,&DATA);
  OutBuffer[n + 1] = SIZE;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    OutBuffer[n + 2 + i] = DATA[i]; // works for array only see Calebs answer to see how it works for structs
  }
  n += SIZE + 1; // +1 to also skip the field for SIZE 
}
```